# 403 forbidden error in IE 11 from IIS application

Tags: iis, internet-explorer-11, http-status-code-403

I'm getting 403-forbidden access denied error in IE 11 when i'm trying to download PDF(application call from IIS).And also same thing working fine in chrome and local development environment(Both IE 11 & Chrome).only issue in IE 11 from calling IIS application.

> Server Error
>
> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
>
> You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether you have allowed Directory Browsing from IIS. You could follow the below steps to allow Directory Browsing.

1. Open **IIS**.
2. Select Your website from Left Pane.
3. Double click **Directory Browsing** from Right Pane.
4. In Right Pane under **Actions** Click **Enable**.

Besides, you could also check you have assigned the IIS_IUSRS security permissions to your assigned web folder. You could check the following steps:

1. Right click on the folder (the folder you assigned for web access in IIS)
2. Choose "Properties" (or "Edit Permissions" if you right clicked while inside the IIS window)
3. Go to "Security" tab
4. In the top box, "Group or user names", open "Edit…" (will take you to Permissions window)
5. You will most likely cannot fine IIS_IUSRS in the list; open, "Add.."
6. In the box at the very bottom, "Enter the object names to select (examples):" enter IIS_IUSRS
7. Click OK and make sure in the Permissions window, you have allowed, Read & execute, List folder contents and Read

Reference: [RESOLVING IIS 403 FORBIDDEN: ACCESS IS DENIED](https://sanuja.com/blog/resolving-iis-403-forbidden-access-is-denied)